# laravel route - search form takes to default path

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the website in a subfolder _demo (laravel app)

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teacode.ma$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.teacode.ma$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !_demo/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /_demo/public/$1 [L]
```

all the routes works except for /courses/search route which takes me to 
http://example.com/_demo/public/courses/search?term=term

Here is the form (should take to http://example.com/courses/search?term=term)

```
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/courses/search/" method="GET">
    <input class="form-control search-input" type="search" name="term" required placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn search-btn" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
  </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share, search url? after the opening before submit

Comment: example.com/courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it , the problem was in the last '/' on the /courses/search/ , I changed it to /courses/search